# PHP Required Fields

Tags: php, html, css, forms, fill

I got the following piece of code in PHP:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_message = $_POST['message'];

$mail_to = 'info@remydesigns.nl';
$subject = 'Bericht van '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'Van: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Bericht: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Bericht mislukt, probeer het nog een keer.');
        window.location = 'index.htm';
    </script>
<?php
}

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Bedankt voor je bericht.');
        window.location = 'index.htm';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Whenever I click on submit even without the fields filled in, it sends an email.
So I am keep getting empty mails from people..

I can't make it check the fields if it is empty or not. What is wrong in my code?

Thanks

EDITED:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $field_name = $_POST['name'];
    $field_email = $_POST['email'];
    $field_message = $_POST['message'];

    $mail_to = 'info@remydesigns.nl';
    $subject = 'Bericht van '.$field_name;

    $body_message = 'Van: '.$field_name."\n";
    $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
    $body_message .= 'Bericht: '.$field_message;

    $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

    $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
}
if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Bedankt voor je bericht.');
        window.location = 'index.htm';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Bericht mislukt, probeer het nog een keer.');
        window.location = 'index.htm';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
    <span>Naam</span> <input class="name" name="name" type="text" /> 
    <span>Email</span> <input class="email" name="email" type="text" /> 
    <span>Bericht</span><textarea class="message" name="message"></textarea> 
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />&nbsp;
</form>
```

Comment: Where is the starting `if` for the `else { ?>`?

Comment: how does this code work in the first place, when you have `else` opened before any `if`? before assigning `$_POST` values, check if they exist with `empty`

Answer (score 2):

use `isset`

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {
     $field_name = $_POST['name'];
     $field_email = $_POST['email'];
     $field_message = $_POST['message'];

     $mail_to = 'info@remydesigns.nl';
     $subject = 'Bericht van '.$field_name;

     $body_message = 'Van: '.$field_name."\n";
     $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
     $body_message .= 'Bericht: '.$field_message;

     $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
     $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

     $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

     if ($mail_status) { ?>
         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
             alert('Bedankt voor je bericht.');
             window.location = 'index.htm';
         </script>
     <?php
     }
     else { ?>
         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
             alert('Bericht mislukt, probeer het nog een keer.');
             window.location = 'index.htm';
         </script>
     <?php
     }
}
```

Comment: If add that to the top line of my code, and click submit, without filled the form in, it still just sending..

Comment: @Remyx11 you also have to write `mail()` inside `if` block. See edited answer.

Comment: Can you check my edit at my original post. Thats how my code is now. Still sends it with out filled in.

Comment: Mm.. used that code, and still won't work.. Maybe something with my HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this to check if it's empty or not also check of `isset`

```
<?php

if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message']))
    die();
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message'])){
now do something
}
```

Comment: @Philipp yes I think there not much security in this case or way to give error so `die();`. It's just give base idea.

Answer (score 0):

try to place the code inside this -

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// send email
}
```

or

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
// send email
}
```

Comment: You can submit a form without click on the submit button - just hit enter in a textbox..